# grid view cells automatically adding 0 at the foot of subtotal grid view

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datagridview

Why are grid view cells automatically adding 0 at the foot of subtotal grid view?

```
        int qty = 0;
        int amount = 0;
        int rowtotal = 0;
        int subtotal = 0;
        int total = 0;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in itemgridview.Rows)
        {
            qty = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value); 
            amount = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value); 
            rowtotal = qty * amount;
            row.Cells[3].Value = rowtotal;
            subtotal += rowtotal;

        }

        total = subtotal;
        txtordertotal.Text = total.ToString();
```

Comment: He means that the 'new row' in the GridView, the part where you would type data to add a row, already has its subtotal prepopulated to 0.

Comment: it is also calculating total for last row as it don't have any values for qty and amount it saving 0 as subtotal has 0 by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `AllowUsersToAddRow = false` and then try again.this property will remove the extra row.

Comment: hey man it works like charm, will it add any duplicates when i try to add all these data's in to database?

Comment: no it will not add any duplicates,if it works for you mark it as answered and ,vote up :-) thanks